# Vertically and horizontally align content in nested css

Tags: html, css

OK, I know that this is an old problem and there are some answers here on Stackoverflow, but none seems to contain a solution for my problem or I'm not fit to understand the answers provided.

I want to align content of one div on a page created with the help of Blueprint CSS horizontally and vertically centered as shown in the picture below and I can't figure out how. Most of the variations I tested use some sort of absolute positioning and all divs end up in the middle of the screen.

[image]

Comment: would you mind to show your code???

Comment: please post relevant HTML and CSS too....what u have tried!

Comment: Have you tried `display:table-cell;` with `vertical-align:middle;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying these styles to the div in which the text should be centered

```
.mydiv{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, most of the other examples included this as well but I simply didn't understand to strip it down to the basics needed.

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose an alternative solution, using this CSS for the alignment:

```
.alignh {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.alignv {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

It requires additional markup, as such:

```
<div class="alignh">
  <div class="alignv">
    <p>I want to be centered horizontally and vertically</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why would it be useful? Because `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` will not work in a div that has `position:absolute` which is something desirable when making columns and rows. Also, placing a div with the `display-table` & `vertical-align` combo inside a div that has absolute position will may be infructuous because you may not be able to make that inner div fill the whole outer div without knowing the size (which may depend on the viewport).

---

The complete code...

HTML:

```
<div class="left col">
  <p>I want to be left aligned</p>
  <p>Me too</p>
  <p>More text</p>
</div>
<div class="right col">
  <div class="top row">
    <div class="alignh">
      <div class="alignv">
        <p>I want to be centered horizontally and vertically</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom row">
    <p>Just some more text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.row {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.row, .col {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left.col {
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
}

.right.col {
  left: 250px;
  right: 0;
}

.top.row {
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.bottom.row {
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.alignh {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.alignv {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[See at Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dhpbj).